# How can i use a lookup table to get a row from a parent table using parameter in django

Tags: python, django

I have the following model in django. What I wanted to do was make a user login a specific service and direct him/her based on the type of the service after login. A user can have maximum one service but a service can have multiple users. However, a service does not necessarily need a user. Hence, I cant create a one-to-one relation with users model. So, i added a second table.

What I want is after a user is logged in, to get the details of the service (id,name and service kind) so I can redirect to the right view based on the kind.

```
class Service(models.Model):

SERVICE_TYPE = (
('Local', 'Local'),
('External', 'External'),
)

name=models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
serviceNature=models.CharField(max_length=25,choices=SERVICE_TYPE,default='Local')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    ordering=('name',)


class ServiceUser(models.Model):
'''
 User to Service
'''
 service=models.ForeignKey(Service,related_name='service_user',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  user=models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='user_service',on_delete=models.CASCADE,unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username + ', ( ' + self.user.first_name + '), ' + self.service.name

class Meta:
    ordering=('service','user')

def myservice(self,user):
  #for the given user, return the service name and type, if exists. I failed to attach it here correctly here.
    return [self.service.id,self.service.name,self.service.serviceNature]
```

I am able to attach a user with a service from the admin area (users dont have staff or super status so they cant login via /admin area). Now I am having issue after the user logs in. In views.py, i have the following login (I have skipped the obvious imports to save space):

```
def login_user(request):
#if form is submitted
form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
logout(request)
if request.method == 'POST':
    #will handle the request later
    username = request.POST['login_email']
    password = request.POST['login_pwd']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            #get the department of the user
            departmentInfo=ServiceUser.myservice(request.user)
            if len(departmentInfo)>0:
                #get the service name and type
                return HttpResponse('You are logged in to ' + str(departmentInfo[0]) + ' ' + departmentInfo[1])
            else:
                form=LoginForm(request.Post)
        else:
            form=LoginForm(request.Post)


else:
    form=LoginForm(request.POST)


#returning form 
return render(request, 'base.html', {'form':form});
```

Now it gives me the error:

myservice(): missing 1 required positional arguement 1 error.

I know my implementation of myservice() method is not correct or the way I am calling it.

How do I go do this? I basically want to make it as short as possible so if i pass the logged in user to myservice, i need to get the service the user is associated with.

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what `my_service` is supposed to do, or why it returns a list. Also, it's an instance method on ServiceUser, but you seem to be calling it as a classmethod.

If you want to go from user to service, you can just follow the relationships: `user.user_service.service`. You can do that directly in your view; there is no need for that method at all.

Comment: Oh thats the relationship, right? Thanks Daniel! Lemme give it a shot. Update: works like a charm! I obviously complicated it or didnt read well :P. Thanks.